# How to show your hidden partial view programmatically in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have  a partial view _ABC.cshtml that is hidden initially.

```
<div id="overview" style="display:none">

    <h1> Overview</h1>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 leftlist">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 overview">
        <h3 class="isppagetitle">@Resources.Overview</h3>
        <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 content">
            <div class="row">
               ......
```

But now from other view I want it to be rendered .

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView("_AMgmtPartial");
    }
```

I did in _AMgmtPartial..

```
<div class="account-root">

    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("_CustList");
        Html.RenderPartial("_ABC", new { style = "display:block" });
    }


    <input type="hidden" id="accountmgmturl" value='@Url.Action("", "AccountMgmt")' />

   ...............
   ...............
```

But this `style="display:block;"` did not work. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: You cannot pass html attributes using `Html.RenderPartial()` - the 2nd parameter is a `ViewDataDictionary`. Why not render the partial inside a hidden `<div>` (located in the main view) instead of having the hidden `<div>` in the partial

Answer (score 3):

`Html.RenderPartial` doesn't have a parameter that accepts HtmlAttributes.  This is confirmed by looking at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial(v=vs.118).aspx) for it.

The parameter that you have populated would be accessible from within the Controller though:

```
public ActionResult Index(string style)
{
    // style will equal "display:block"

    return PartialView("_AMgmtPartial");
}
```

You could take this value and pass it to your partial view via the view bag or a view model.

```
public ActionResult Index(string style = "display: none")
{
    // style will equal "display:block"

    ViewBag.PartialStyle = style;

    return PartialView("_AMgmtPartial");
}
```

Then this makes it accessible from within your view:

```
<div id="overview" style="@ViewBag.PartialStyle">

    <h1> Overview</h1>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 leftlist">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 overview">
        <h3 class="isppagetitle">@Resources.Overview</h3>
        <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 content">
            <div class="row">
               ......
```

To do this though would be a dirty hack.  As @Stephen mentioned a more preferable solution would be to wrap your partial view render statement in a `<div>` and on that you should set your initial visibility.

```
<div style="display: block">
    @Html.Partial("_ABC");
</div>
```

Comment: I was writing the same answer. This is the correct way.